# Ethereum Token Nam Redundancy

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I have created a ERC20 token in ethereum blockchain with token name as TestToken and Symbol as TTT. Now how can I ensure that others cant create a token with the same name and same symbol? Is there is any way to ensure the redundancy in token name?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience no, the trick is that you have a unique contract address you can use. So there can be an unlimited number of tokens with the same name, the trick is that they will each have their own address.  For example Gnosis' contract is at     0x6810e776880c02933d47db1b9fc05908e5386b96.  So while you can make as many coins name Gnosis as you would like, the actual Gnosis is the only one that can have that address

Answer (score 0):

At this moment there is no way to reserve a token name or symbol. There's nothing stoping someone from using the same name name or symbol other existing tokens have.